# How to check that one specific value is exist in first coumn or second column in sql?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

1. I have one value. Now,I want to check that value is exist in
   'from_user_id' column or 'to_user_id' column and then I want to
   return last record which contains that value which will be in either
   'from_user_id' or 'to_user_id' column.

   ```
   $query3 = $this->db->query("select * from message where 26 
   IN(from_user_id,to_user_id) desc limit 1");
   foreach($query3->result() as $row)
   {
      $message = $row->message;
   }
   ```

   I have tried this.but it's not working.

   ```
   $query3 = $this->db->query("select * from message where 26 
   IN(from_user_id,to_user_id)");

   foreach($query3->result() as $row)
   {
       $message = $row->message;
   }
   ```

   I also tried this which is not giving me last record.

Comment: `IN()` contains a value to find and `$str[$i]`  is field in which you want to find, you just need a two  `OR`  where condition

Comment: last record then apply `order by` and `top 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM message 
WHERE from_user_id = 26 OR to_user_id = 26
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

suppose, that in your message table you have integer primary key as *id*. If not, update the order by statement to the proper field

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to check this

```
 $this->db->where('from_user_id', 26);
 $this->db->or_where('to_user_id', 26);
 $result = $this->db->get('message')->result();

 if(isset($result) && count($result) > 0){ 
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
        $message = $row->message;
     }
  }else{
     echo 'No result found';  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make an active record like this :

```php
$id = 26;
$this->db->where('from_user_id', $id)
    ->or_where('to_user_id', $id)
    ->order_by('message_id','desc')
    ->limit(1);
$query3 = $this->db->get('message')->row();

if (!empty($query3)) {
    $message = $query3->message;
} else {
    echo 'No message found!';
}
```

Where `message_id` is the message table id.

Comment: what do you mean use join? where's your join?

Comment: also do you want to use query builder (active record) or just a native query?